# Is it possible to make a remote server part of VPN so that only machines within a domain network can access the server?

Tags: network, vpn, cloud-computing, lan

First, let me describe the problem I am trying to solve.

- I have a domain-based network. My Source Control server resides on
  this network. This meant only devices connected to the network (part
  of the domain) could access the Source Control server.
- Now I decided to move the Source Control server to a Cloud based
  server. The Cloud    based server is a IAAS (Infrastructure as a
  Service), which basically    means I am doing RDP to the server and
  all that.
- Now for security    reasons, it is essential that only devices within
  the network (LAN) can    access the Source Control server on the Cloud, as
  before. Any device    outside my domain network should not have
  access to the Source    Control server.

  The problem is the Source Control server is now there on the Internet.

I have done some research and it seems like VPN is what I am looking for. Essentially my domain network and my remote server should all be part of the same VPN. Any device outside my domain network will not be able to access the VPN. Am I in the right direction ? How can I achieve this ?

I have googled a lot but haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: A "virtual private network" is indeed made for this very purpose. I'm not sure this is a security question, though. It is more of a networking question. You need a VPN node on the LAN that connects to the VPN node on the remote side.

Comment: Search term: site to site VPN: https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/site-to-site-routing-explained-in-detail/

Comment: Thanks for your reference. I found it useful